# Timeline: advancing time without evaluating time

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

While placing keyframes in the timeline it is possible to move the time marker (green vertical line) without evaluating the animation?

On my object, I have some keyframes values that I want to be exactly the same, some keyframes later. This is to hold the position of my object before moving it after a certain amount of time.

Coming from Maya this was possible. Is this possible too in Blender?

Comment: You can type in the exact keyframe on the bottom, and it will skip all intermediate frames

Comment: Open a Dope Sheet Editor window. Using it you may place the animation markers wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!
Moving keyframes in the DopeSheet is awesome.
Learnt something new about Blender.